# Reduced row echelon form of binary matrix in MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hello everybody I try to find Reduced row echelon form for binary matrix in matlab. Does mathlab contain any functions to do that?
Standart rref computes it only for real numbers.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "only for real numbers"? If your matrix is binary, it can be converted to real numbers with `double`

Comment: I mean i need to use binary arithmetics. 1+1 = 0.

Comment: last time I checked `1+1=10` not `0`...

Comment: all calculations are made by modulo 2

Answer (score 0):

```
[m,n]=size(a);
b=a;

c=0;

for k=1:min(m,n)

    c=c+1;
i=find(b(:,k));

i(i strictly less c)=[ ];

  if (~isempty(i)) 

    imax=min(i);
    b([c imax],:)=b([imax c],:);

    ck=b(c,:);
p=find(b(:,k));

p(p==c)=[];

    if ~isempty(p)

       v=b(p,:)+repmat(ck,length(p),1);
       b(p,:)=mod(v,2);
    end;
  else
       c=c-1;  
  end;

end;
```